# How to migrate Products, Order, Customers data from one WooComerce to existing WooCommerce website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, data-migration

I have 2 WooCommerce websites, for example, www.oldweb.com, and www.newweb.com

www.oldweb.com is an active and live website that means it has more new customers, orders and products. However, the www.newweb.com is more updated with look n feel and other website's pages and content but outdated with products, categories, orders, and users.

Is there any way to just migrate only orders, products, users, and categories from www.oldweb.com to www.newweb.com without any paid plugins and without overriding the blog post, pages data and breaking the layout of the website?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is through WordPress: **Tools** > **Export**, so you just select **Products** (already includes categories) and **Orders** to export. About Export and Import **Users**, you can use a plugin like [Import Export Wordpress Users](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/) by [WebToffee](https://www.webtoffee.com/). It's easy, you only need to install the plugin on each site and Export/Import users.

Hope this tip helps you.

Answer (score 1):

As replied earlier, in addition to [users export and import](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/), products and orders can also be imported or exported using [Product Import Export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/) and [Orders Import Export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-import-export-for-woocommerce/).  These free export/import plugins serve the custom needs of the store owner with support. It also offers export/import of data using:
 - both CSV/XML file
 - a specific number of items using offset and limit
 - specific columns only, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this free plugin: [Store to WooCommerce Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextcart-woocommerce-migration/)

It worked well in my Woo store.

If you new WooCommerce is online, don't forget to create a backup before the migration.